# Directive: Link function children not interpolating values

Tags: angularjs-directive

I am trying to output child element id in a directive, but it keeps printing non-interpolated values. I don't know how to achieve that....please help.

I am trying to learn angular...

```
//////////////////////
//Directive example 
app.directive('simpleNumber', ['$http', '$compile', function($http, $compile) {

return {
    restrict: 'A',      /*Example: <span simple-number></span>*/
    terminal: true,
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,      /*Replace <simple-number-ctrl> tag with below template*/
    template: "<div><div id=\"{{$id}}\"></div></div> ",

    scope: {    /*data-binding to parent scope*/
        ctrlWidth: "@",     /*one way binding*/
        strNumber: "=",     /*two way binding*/
        onWidthChanged: "&"     /*Event function fired*/
    },

    link: function($scope, elm, attrs) {
        console.log(elm.children()[0].id);                  //This is printing {{$id}} !!! I AM CONFUSED
    }
};

}]);


<span simple-number ctrl-width="100px" str-number="numberText" on-width-changed="onWidthChanged(width);"><font color=green>Transcluded text</font></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the linking function is called, the `{{ }}` bindings are not evaluated yet, so you still have them as raw text. You will get the correct value once the $digest cycle is finished.
Use this in your link function if you want to better understand what is going on.

```
link: function($scope, elm, attrs) {
    console.log("bindings not evaluated yet:",element.html());
    var unwatch = scope.$watch(function(){
        console.log("after $digest, bindings are evaluated",element.html());
        unwatch();
    });
}
```

Comment: Following is console output

**Before bindings are evaluated.**
bindings not evaluated yet: <div id="{{$id}}"></div>

**After digest is called** (As per your example)
after $digest, bindings are evaluated <div id="{{$id}}"></div>

Comment: Strange, I remember testing it before sending the solution. Could you try without the unwatch() call ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using $timeout (see code below). I don't know why it's working this way. Can someone provide an explanation?

```
//////////////////////
//Directive example 
app.directive('simpleNumber', ['$http', '$compile', function($http, $compile) {

return {
    restrict: 'A',      /*Example: <span simple-number></span>*/
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,      /*Replace <simple-number-ctrl> tag with below template*/
    template: "<div><div id=\"{{$id}}\"></div></div> ",

    link: function($scope, elm, attrs) {
        //Print children ID's
        var __debugOutputChildrenInfo = function(children)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
                console.log(children[i].id);
        }

        var children = elm.children();
        __debugOutputChildrenInfo(children); //Prints {{$id}}  [Shouldn't binding have been resolved by now?]

        //Don't understand why this is working...need explanation?
        $timeout(function() {
            __debugOutputChildrenInfo(children); //Prints 002 [THIS IS WHAT I WANTED..NEED EXPLANATION]
        });
    }
};

}]);


<span simple-number ctrl-width="100px" str-number="numberText" on-width-changed="onWidthChanged(width);"><font color=green>Transcluded text</font></span>
```